# jQuery selector with this reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group  btn-group-justified"> 
     <a id="option1" data-option="1" class="btn btn-default" href="#">3</a>
     <a id="option2" data-option="2" class="btn btn-default" href="#">6</a>
     <a id="option3" data-option="3" class="btn btn-default" href="#">9</a>
     <a id="option4" data-option="4" class="btn btn-default" href="#">12</a>
     <a id="option5" data-option="5" class="btn btn-default" href="#">15</a>
</div>

    <p id="pp"></p>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$("[id^='option']").click(function () {
    $("#pp").html(this.attr("data-option"));
});
```

The codes are simplified to point the problem easier.

What I want to do is getting `data-option` attribute value of clicked `a` element to the `p` element with `id="pp"`.

Something is wrong with `this` reference I guess. 
I do not want to write the same code 5 times,  so I tried to use *starts with operator* I think `this` reference refers to something else.

Comment: use `$(this)` instead of `this`

Comment: There is no "data" attribute. Data attributes begin with `data-` and are followed by at least one character. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-*

Comment: @j08691 I have learned something new. Thanks.

Comment: Don't change answers when you edit your question. Instead post comment telling you edited and the answers can be edited to reflect required changes as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside the handler `this` refers to the dom element, it does not have `.attr()` method so you need to get the jQuery wrapper reference for that element using `$(this).attr('data-option')`

```
$("[id^='option']").click(function () {
    $("#pp").html($(this).attr("data-option"));//since the attribute is `data-option` $(this).data("option") also will work
});
```

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ since the attribute is `data-option` $(this).data("option") also will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native JavaScript method `getAttribute()`:

```
$("[id^='option']").click(function () {
    $("#pp").html(this.getAttribute("data"));
});
```

However now that you made it into actual data attribute, simply use such code instead:

```
$("[id^='option']").click(function () {
    var oClickedItem = $(this);
    $("#pp").html(oClickedItem.data("option"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^='option']").click(function(){
        $("#pp").html($(this).attr("data"));
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sZgcU/)**</kbd>